# I am able to store image in database but how to display image

Tags: php

This part of the code is upload image into the database and save but how do i retrieve the image and display? Below are the code that i have done .

```
<!doctype html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <?php
        include("config.php");

        if(isset($_POST['but_upload'])){
            $name = $_FILES['file']['name'];
            $target_dir = "upload/";
            $target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["file"]["name"]);

            // Select file type
            $imageFileType = strtolower(pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION));

            // Valid file extensions
            $extensions_arr = array("jpg","jpeg","png","gif");

            // Check extension
            if( in_array($imageFileType,$extensions_arr) ){

                // Convert to base64 
                $image_base64 = base64_encode(file_get_contents($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']) );
                $image = 'data:image/'.$imageFileType.';base64,'.$image_base64;

                // Insert record
                $query = "insert into images(name,image) values('".$name."','".$image."')";

                mysqli_query($con,$query) or die(mysqli_error($con));

                // Upload file
                move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'],'upload/'.$name);

            }

        }
        ?>
    <body>
        <form method="post" action="" enctype='multipart/form-data'>
            <input type='file' name='file' />
            <input type='submit' value='Save name' name='but_upload'>
        </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

The above code i got this from a website call http://makitweb.com/upload-and-store-an-image-in-the-database-with-php/

below this line is the code i do not know where to add
where do i add the below code can help me edit?

```
<?php

 $sql = "select image from images where id=1";
 $result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
 $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);

 $image_src2 = $row['image'];

?>
<img src='<?php echo $image_src; ?>' >
```

Comment: what does this have to do with Visual Studio or C#?

Answer (score 0):

Create another script, let's call it `image.php`, with the following content:

```
<?php

$sql = "select image from images where id=1";
$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);

$image_src2 = $row['image'];
echo $image_src; 
?>
```

This is what you should use, as in `<img src="image.php">`. Probably you need to set the proper header values according to the type of image you are using

Answer (score 0):

in this `<img src='<?php echo $image_src; ?>' >` php code will not execute html thinks it as some value either remove `''` or

do like this

```
echo "<img src=$image_src >";
```

in php too, php operations inside "" or '' will not execute